# Why am I getting an attribute error?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

The data returned by method `self.prepSetFile()` is of type dictionary

```
    dataTodump=self.prepSetFile()
    try:
        settingFile=os.path.join(self.settingsDir,"setting.txt")
        output_phil=open(settingFile,'w')
        pickle.dump(dataTodump,settingFile,0)
    except: raise
```

I do not know why I am getting Attribute error

> AttributeError:
>   'str' object has no attribute 'write'

I even tested the data type of dataTodump which is obviously dict

Comment: *Always* include the *full* traceback when reporting a Python exception.

Comment: `except: raise`, why do you even need `try-catch` then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass in an *open* file to `pickle.dump`; you are passing in a filename only:

```
output_phil=open(settingFile,'wb')
pickle.dump(dataTodump, output_phil, 0)
```

Note that the file is opened in *binary* mode to prevent `\n` bytes being translated on non-UNIX platforms.

Comment: or better: `pickle.dump(dataTodump, output_phil, 0)`

Comment: @glglgl: almost; added a `wb` binary mode to it now.